# How do i disable autoresizingmask constraints in collection view cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, flowlayout

I am using collection view with flow layout. But it doesn't work the way i want.

UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout methods are calling, but sizes for cells are different at run time.

In debug view hierarchy i noticed some strange constraints, like:
`self.width = 201` or `self.minX = 255.5`

i tried set `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` but since my cells are created from xib it doesn't work.
I am using latest Xcode. Thank you for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I set `collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()` and it worked as expected now